# Como pegar as informações de itens de uma listview java e inseri-las em um textview android studio?

Tags: android, listview, lista, view, textview

Estou aprendendo a programar, e comecei um projeto em q mostra as informações sobre as equipes de Formula 1, tais como pilotos, idade, nacionalidade e títulos de cada um.
[image]

Ao clicar em um item, será levado a uma Activity contendo as informações sobre a equipe tocada.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Queria poder pegar essas informaçoes e mandar nos textview.

```
public class Ferrari{
        String nomePiloto1 = "Sebastian Vettel";
        String idadePiloto1 = "25 anos";
        String titulosPiloto1 = "4 títulos";
        String nacionalPiloto1 = "Alemanha";
        int fotoPiloto1 = R.drawable.vettel;
        String nomePiloto2 = "Kimi Raikkonen";
        String idadePiloto2 = "29 anos";
        String titulosPiloto2 = "1 titulo";
        String nacionalPiloto2 = "Finlandia";
        int fotoPiloto2 = R.drawable.raikkonen;
    }
```

Cada equipe possui um public class igual, só muda as informaçoes entre aspas.

Comment: um conselho é parares de usar listview e começar a usar recycler view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você quer passar essas informações para uma `TextView` em outra `Activity` você pode usar `listView.setOnItemClickListener()` e passar os dados via `Intent`:

Activity da lista de Equipes

```
 public static final String KEY_EQUIPE = "equipe"; 

 //onCreate
 ...

 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Equipe equipe = list.get(position);
        Intent intent = new Intent(ListEquipesActivity.this, DetalhesEquipesActivity.class)
        intent.putExtra(KEY_EQUIPE , equipe);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Activity da lista de Pilotos

```
 public static final String KEY_EQUIPE = "equipe";

 public static final String KEY_PILOTO = "piloto";

 //no onCreate
 ...

 Intent intent = getIntent();
 Equipe equipe = intent.getSerializableExtra

 //Como são apenas dois pilotos por equipe e já tem esses argumentos na sua classe Equipe, você pode fazer isso estaticamente
 //Se o número de pilotos de cada equipe não for um número estático, você terá que mudar o construtor da sua classe
 //para construir um piloto de cada vez e fazer um Adapter para tal


 //Forma de setar os nomes com layout atual
 TextView nomePiloto1 = findViewbyid(R.id.nome_piloto_1);
 nomePiloto1.setText(equipe.getNomePiloto1);
 //Faça isso para todas as outras TextViews


 //Funcionará assim se o número de pilotos não for estático
 //Se quiser ter o mesmo resultado com o código atual pode setar um OnClickListener para cada layout de piloto

 ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listView) //Recupera sua listView no Java
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Piloto piloto = list.get(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(ListActivity.this, DetalhesActivity.class)
            intent.putExtra(KEY_PILOTO, piloto);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Activity de detalhes

```
 public static final String KEY_PILOTO = "piloto";

 //No onCreate()
 Intent intent = getIntent();
 Piloto piloto= intent.getSerializableExtra(KEY_PILOTO);

 TextView textDetalhesNome = findViewById(R.id.text_detalhes_nome);
 textDetalhesNome.setText(piloto.getNomePiloto1()); 

 TextView textDetalhesIdade = findViewById(R.id.text_detaçhes_idade);
 textdetalhesIdade.setText(piloto.getIdadePiloto1());
 //Adicione mais o que quiser aqui, foi só um ex
```

> Sua classe Piloto e Equipe precisa implementar a interface Serializable para isso funcionar
>
> "Criei" uma classe Piloto caso queira usar esse código depois

Como todas as classes de Equipes são iguais utilize só uma classe chamada Equipe para criar os itens da lista, isso facilita a escrita e a leitura do código

Comment: Mas como são dois pilotos a serem mostrados não seria necessário "idade1"ïdade2" e assim por diante?

Comment: Se você deseja mostrar antes uma lista de equipes crie uma classe com nome de "Equipe" em vez de "Ferrari" (caso tenham os mesmos atributos), assim facilita a leitura do código. Se quer mostrar uma lista na outra Activity você terá que passar um objeto "Equipe" contendo os pilotos respectivos e só nessa lista botar o código de mostrar o piloto acima, como você passou a classe com nome de piloto e etc. eu achei q eram os detalhes do piloto, desculpe. Vou atualizar o código

Comment: A lista quero deixar como está, só quero criar um perfil pra cada equipe mostrando os dados dos pilotos

Comment: Vê se agora está do jeito certo. Eu deixei a parte que mostra os detalhes do piloto pra se você quiser usar futuramente